# OSMnx: Pyproj Projection error when when creating graph from OSM

Tags: python, osmnx, pyproj

I'm using OSMnx to pull data from Open Street Maps using the function:

```
G= ox.graph_from_place('Alberta, Canada')
```

But when I do I get the following error

> File "C:\Users\me\test.py", line 22, in
>
> G= ox.graph_from_place('Alberta, Canada')
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\graph.py",
> line 327, in graph_from_place
> gdf_place = geocoder.geocode_to_gdf(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\osmnx\geocoder.py",
> line 114, in geocode_to_gdf
> gdf.crs = settings.default_crs
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py",
> line 199, in **setattr**
> super().**setattr**(attr, val)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
> line 5500, in **setattr**
> return object.**setattr**(self, name, value)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py",
> line 423, in crs
> self.geometry.values.crs = value
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\geopandas\array.py",
> line 336, in crs
> self._crs = None if not value else CRS.from_user_input(value)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py",
> line 479, in from_user_input
> return cls(value, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\me\anaconda3\envs\ox\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py",
> line 326, in **init**
> self._local.crs = _CRS(self.srs)
>
> File "pyproj_crs.pyx", line 2352, in pyproj._crs._CRS.**init**
>
> CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:4326: (Internal Proj Error:
> proj_create: no database context specified)

I downloaded OSMNX through the recommended conda install method using the following code in the conda prompt:

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

I've reinstalled OSMnx, updated the pyproj package, I've tried uninstalling the pyproj package and reainstalling an earlier version of pyproj but it messes with all the dependencies.The only similar issue I have found with pyproj is where Windows has installation issues with pyproj>=2.0.0 [link here](https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/216)

Comment: Can you provide more troubleshooting details? What versions of OSMnx and pyproj and python? What OS?

Comment: Yes sorry for the limited version details. This is from my ox environment using conda list: 
|osmnx                     1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge |                                        
pyproj                    3.2.1            py39h39b2389_2    conda-forge|
python                    3.9.7           h7840368_3_cpython    conda-forge|

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: My OS is Windows 10.